# SAS - Advanced querying

Tags: sql, sas

I have one SQL table with the data in SAS.  The first column is a datetime, and there is one row for each second. The set spans for about 20 minutes.  The other columns contain integer values.

Here is what I need:

For example, Let's pick 50.  How many times did the integer value go from below 50 to above 50 and stay above 50 for at least n seconds.

Is it possible to conduct such analysis with proc sql?  If yes, how so, and if not, how else?

I am new to SAS, so any help is appreciated.  Let me know if you need more info!

Thanks!

Comment: Why not try analyzing it visually? - something like [proc sgplot](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/69716/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1mp0swy0atvzun1oeqlkrg8d89o.htm). It could be a bar chart of datetime in x-axis and integer value in y-axis and a line chart of y=50

Comment: Please make some sample input data, and add it to your question. Also add the output you would want from your sample. Sample data makes it easier for people to understand your question, and easier for them to try out solutions. Doesn't feel like a SQL problem to me, but should be reasonable DATA step solutions.

Comment: What @Quentin said. You always want to provide input and (simulated) output data, and any draft code which shows how far you got before you got stuck, or at least mention specific syntax or functions you tried using. could you edit the question. It would then get more traction and upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

> How many times did the integer value go from below/above 50

I think this could be solution to first part of the question. Resolution is maybe the best obtained by comparing current value with prior

```
data begin; /*Some test data...*/
    input int_in_question;
    datalines;
    51
    51
    49
    55
    55
    40
    40
    60
    40
    ;
run;

data With_calc;
    set begin;
    if int_in_question < 50 and 
        lag(int_in_question)>=50 
            then Times_below_50+1;
run;
```